# sum function with variables R

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

I am new in R and I am trying to create the function below for several terms.
Is there any way to create the sum of this function: (1,000 * ( 1.1 )^ −2 + 2,000 * ( 1.1 )^−4)
where the numbers 1.000,2000 are variables and the numbers 2,4 correspond to these variables?
(For example 1000—>2 and 2000—>4)
(This example has just 2 terms and 4 variables and I want to create the sum for  terms=variables/2)

Comment: (x * ( 1.1 )^ −2 + y * ( 1.1 )^−4)  where c(x,y) and the numbers 2 and 4 correspond to x and y respectively.  Maybe I need a loop, I am not really sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
a <- c(1000, 2000)
b <- c(2, 4)
sum(a * 1.1^(-b))
```